# Merge Android Options Menu with Actionbar

Tags: android, merge, android-actionbar, overflow

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbdyv.jpg

Can't seem to find the answer to this question. I've tried all sorts of different android tags for the File option.

I know that you can set 
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"

in your manifest but that just puts the options at the bottom of the screen.

Ideally I'd like to have, Tab1 Tab2 Tab3 Tab4 : <-(triple dot overflow)

For some reason my application creates this new bar beneath my action bar with the triple dots in it?

Here is my code

Manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestForActionBarActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>

main_options.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/file"
      android:title="File" >
</item>
</menu>
```

Activity
    package test.actionbar;

```
public class TestForActionBarActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 1");
    tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(){

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 2");
    tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(){

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);

    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 3");
    tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(){

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);

    ActionBar.Tab tab4 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 4");
    tab4.setTabListener(new TabListener(){

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
    actionBar.addTab(tab4);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_options, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is the design pattern for an action bar with tabs on a narrow (phone) screen. There are screenshots in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) under the "Adding Navigation Tabs" section.

[Phone stacked](http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-stacked.png)

Answer (score 0):

It creates it because you have

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

in the code. You can comment it out and have another tab with image if tripledot at the end.